# How to write the content in MS Excel 2007?

Tags: windows, excel

Consider I have a Excel sheet and when I (typed the data in the `A1 cell` that
will automatically load on the `Cell B1`

How can I do that in the Microsoft Excel 2007?.. Please give a solution for that.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try typing `=A1` in your B1 cell.